# Unexpected behaviour with FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

Why does `System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo()` return unexpected file version information? I'm looking for version information about MPIO drivers. The target OS is Server 2008R2 SP1, which should return FileVersion 6.1.7601. Instead of that, I got 2008R2 RTM version of 6.1.7600.

In addition to incorrect file version, the OriginalFilename is not what I'd expect it to be either. It's mpio.sys.mui, though FileName is correct.

Correct version information is displayed when examining file's properties with Explorer.

Is this by design, a bug or am I using FileVersionInfo erroneus a way? Are there any workarounds, preferably on Powershell?

```
$mpioPath = 'c:\windows\system32\drivers\mpio.sys'
$v = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($mpioPath)
$v | fl -Property *

Comments           :
CompanyName        : Microsoft Corporation
FileBuildPart      : 7601
FileDescription    : MultiPath Support Bus-Driver
FileMajorPart      : 6
FileMinorPart      : 1
FileName           : c:\windows\system32\drivers\mpio.sys
FilePrivatePart    : 17619
FileVersion        : 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)
InternalName       : mpio.sys
IsDebug            : False
IsPatched          : False
IsPrivateBuild     : False
IsPreRelease       : False
IsSpecialBuild     : False
Language           : English (United States)
LegalCopyright     : © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
LegalTrademarks    :
OriginalFilename   : mpio.sys.mui
PrivateBuild       :
ProductBuildPart   : 7601
ProductMajorPart   : 6
ProductMinorPart   : 1
ProductName        : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
ProductPrivatePart : 17619
ProductVersion     : 6.1.7600.16385
SpecialBuild       :
```

The same result is achieved with a C# program, so this seems to be more of .Net feature than Powershell specific one.

```
namespace Foo {
  class GetFileVersionInfo {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      string mpio = @"c:\windows\system32\drivers\mpio.sys";
      System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo fvInfo;
      fvInfo = System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(mpio);
      System.Console.WriteLine("Original file name: " + fvInfo.OriginalFilename);
      System.Console.WriteLine("FileVersion: " + fvInfo.FileVersion);
    }
  }
}
```

Using FileVer.exe returns correct version info:

```
filever $mpioPath
--a-- W32  DRV ENU  6.1.7601.17619 shp    156,544 05-20-2011 mpio.sys
```

I could user FileVer and parse its output, if nothing else works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess FileVer.exe and expolrer.exe doing the same as you can do in powershell:

```
$mpioPath = 'c:\windows\system32\drivers\mpio.sys'
$v = [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($mpioPath)

$ver = "{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}" -f $v.FileMajorPart, $v.FileMinorPart, $v.FileBuildPart, $v.FilePrivatePart
```

Comment: I accept this as the answer, though it doesn't explain why the version information is not consistent.

Answer (score 2):

At the [MSDN page for GetFileVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it says:

> File version info has fixed and non-fixed part. The fixed part contains information like version number. The non-fixed part contains things like strings. In the past GetFileVersionInfo was taking version information from the binary (exe/dll). Currently, it is querying fixed version from language neutral file (exe/dll) and the non-fixed part from mui file, merges them and returns to the user.

So this corresponds to exactly what you saw: one version number comes from `c:\windows\system32\drivers\mpio.sys` and the other comes from `c:\windows\system32\drivers\[your language]\mpio.sys.mui`

Answer (score 1):

To my knowlege the fields "FileVersion" and "ProductVersion" are unicode **strings**. In contrast the fields "FileMajorPart", "FileMinorPart", "FileBuildPart" and "FilePrivatePart" are **DWORD values**. The fields "ProductMajorPart", "ProductMinorPart", "ProductBuildPart" and "ProductPrivatePart" are DWORD values too:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The applications used to create the VersionBlock might allow inconsistencies between the strings and the DWORD fields. Some versions of Visual Studio for example will always update the DWORD fields to reflect the changes made to the strings. However an update to the DWORD value alone does not reflect in the strings. Thus depending on the applications used for coding **different degrees of inconsistencies are possible**. In my experience you will get the best results with the DWORD fields alone (as it has been proposed in the answer to your question).